# PHP Library to test loading speeds

Tags: php, yslow, pagespeed

I was wondering whether there is a simple PHP library to test the loading speed of a web page or a single resource similar to Google Page Speed and Yahoo! YSlow.
The reason is that I'd like to build a web based alternative.

Comment: Do you mean testing your own page's loading speed or that of other pages?

Comment: Are you trying to build something similar to: http://www.webpagetest.org/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageSpeed and YSlow run in the browser and do not only measure loading of *one* URL, but also of all resources linked on that URL in addition to `@import` and `url()` directives in CSS files and [javascript resources lazy loaded](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript) while the DOM is loading. I doubt this can be done easily/at all with PHP without running the code through a [server side JS engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) as well.

Consider this snippet of [Dojo code](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/modules-and-namespaces/what-does-dojo-require-):

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
```

or this JavaScript code:

```
document.write('<script src="', 
               'http://example.com/other.js', 
               '" type="text/JavaScript"><\/script>');
```

Given the number of possible approaches out there, this is virtually impossible to catch from PHP. If you still want to try, check out the [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [HTTP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php).

Or consider measuring from the browser with JavaScript, e.g. something like http://webwait.com/

Comment: Agreed, it won't be easy, but somehow there are sites already doing that, and I don't think they have a browser instance running somewhere.

Comment: @cdecker well, ask them how they do it then. Worst thing that can happen is they don't respond at all.

Comment: Well as far as I can see there is no simple solution to this problem. My best guess would be to hook into a real webbrowser such as wkhtmltopdf (http://bit.ly/dpubxW) and record loading times.
So I guess your answer was the most helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$start=microtime(1);
copy($url,"/dev/null");
echo "$url page loading time is: ".round(microtime(1)-$start,4);
```

?